# How can I sum up every second number in list

Tags: python, list, for-loop, while-loop, sum

Given that a list

```
[10,20,30,40,50,60]
```

If I want to sum up every second number. For instance `20+40+60=120`.
So what should I write in python? Is it while loop or for loop?

Comment: Use a slice with a stride of 2, and the `sum()` function.

Comment: You're better off finding a tutorial on Python looping.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation for information about slicing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
nth = 2

values = [10,20,30,40,50,60]

total = sum(values[1::nth])

print(total)
```